# Second stage bootloader filename does not work with lowercase

Tags: assembly, filenames, bootloader, x86-16

I am referring to BrokenThorn's tutorial on OS development and am currently at the chapter on writing the first stage bootloader and loading the second stage.

I wrote the whole code and ran into crashes on running it using qemu.
After some debugging, I found out that the problem was with the name of the second stage bootloader, which I'm reading by looping through the root directory entries.

If I use the filename for the second stage as INITKRNL.BIN, everything works fine. But if I use initkrnl.bin (thus the difference being only in the case of the name), it crashes.

I also printed the name being read from the root directory. For the upper case name, it reads INITKRNL.BIN only. For the lower case name, it reads some letters of the name and some random characters.

Why does the case of the file name matter, and what is the reason for this difference ?

Note : I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 as my development environment. I format the floppy image with the VFAT file system using `mkfs.vfat`.

Comment: I don't know what environment you're running this in, but aren't most filesystems these days case sensitive? (even NTFS, although the Win32 APIs chooses to view it as case insensitive).

Comment: @Michael: Linux. I'm booting off a floppy image formatted with the VFAT file system.

Comment: FAT12 stores the filename in uppercase, and the '.' is not stored (space padded to 8 if the "first name" is less than 8).

Comment: @FrankKotler : Okay. So even if I store the file as initkrnl.asm, it would actually be stored as INITKRNL.ASM. So when I read the root directory entry, I should be getting INITKRNL.ASM only, right ? But that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually stored as an 11 char string, in the 8.3 format (8 characters for filename, 3 characters for extension). So in ram it would be `INITKRNLASM`.

Also, I would recommend against using the VFAT filesystem on a floppy drive, and to instead use the FAT12 filesystem, as it is simpler and more suitable for media of that size.